# Certificates ( *.p12 , *.cert ) in azure - webjob

Tags: azure, wcf, ssl, wcf-security, azure-keyvault

I have created a WebJob in .Net Framework 4.5.  This webjob is consuming a traditional WCF service which is protected by certificates ( Public/private key ).  I have imported all the required certificates in my local computer and I was able to communicate with the WCF service.  Below is sample code that is fetching certificate from local store.

```
 X509Certificate2 tlsCert = X509CertificateUtil.GetCertificate(
            "39834391cba4e625bab0cba7838247ec6b53d92d",
            X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
            StoreName.TrustedPeople,
            StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
            true
            );
```

and then use `tlsCert` further to execute WCF contract.

I am not sure how to do this when I am hosting this in Azure.  How do I import the certificate and access certificate store in Azure?
Note: We are not using VM to deploy WebJob in azure.  we are using 'Appservice' plan to host the webjob.

Any direction how to deal with the certificates?  I am trying to get it done using KeyVault, but not sure if it will work or not.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure KeyVault, certificates can be imported in either PFX or PEM format, so the formats you mentioned won't work unless you convert them to PEM or PFX.

Here are [some instructions](https://gist.github.com/shahdhiren/9ca059ac0762f7ef0fcf71a79ed5b022) for how to do that.

See more information about importing KeyVault certificates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates).

Comment: Some confusing thing is that I read that P12 is just a PFX with another extension. I renamed P12 to PFX and was able to import it to Keyvault. Issue, Expiration date, subject were all recognized... For now this is an internal keyvault with a couple of us with access to it.